# Rails 4 - Rspec request test post with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a working code and I am trying to write a rspec request spec for the following

form

```
      <%= semantic_form_for @student, :url => student_documents_path(@student), method: :post do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :documents, @student.documents.new do |form| %>
          <%= render 'students/document', :f => form %>
        <% end %>
      <%end%>
```

Controler

```
class Students::DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @student.update_attributes!(documents_params)
   redirect_to student_path(@student)
  end
```

end

Request spec

```
  describe 'POST #create' do
  it 'should be successful' do
    post "/students/#{student_1.id}/documents", student: { :document_entries_attributes => { "0" => {year: 2017, category: 'bla'} } }

    expect(student_1.documents.count).to eq(1)

  end
end
```

nested attributes does not get saved. is it because I have not 
@student.documents.new in the test ? any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Just to confirm, it works in the UI right? If yes, try student_1.reload.documents.count

Comment: yes it works fine on UI and saves the nested record fine

Answer (score 0):

Try with FactoryGirl

```
it "redirects to the home page upon save" do
  post :create, student: Factory.attributes_for(:student)
  expect(student_1.documents.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Follow this [link](https://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html)